# Expected value of an exponent of integer rv

Tags: probability

A person enters the casino and betting on his money in several rounds. In each round he bets all his money and wins with prob $p$ (and lose in prob $1-p$). Each round is independent of all the previous rounds, if he wins his sum of money is doubled and if he looses it halved.

The games ends as soon as he looses twice (not necessary in a row).

I need to find the probability $p$ for which the expected value of the sum is 4 times as big as the initial value.

I tried solving that by defining the integer valued rv $$X = \#num\_of\_rounds$$
which is the sum of two geometric random variable with prob $1-p$ for stop, and by that we can get that the expected mean of $X$ is the sum of expected means of the two geometric rvs, i.e,
$$E(X) = \frac{2}{1-p}$$

Now defining $$Y = sum\_of\_money\_at\_the\_end$$
we get that $$Y = 2^{X-4}\times S$$ when $S$ is the initial value of money the man has when he enters.

Now by setting the limitation $$E(2^{X-4}) = 4$$ I should get the expected result, but I cant figure how to calculate $E(2^{X-4})$

Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: In full generality, $$E(2^{X-4})=\sum_n2^{n-4}P(X=n).$$ So if you know each $P(X=n)$, everything is cool. Do you? Another option when $X=Y+Z$ with $Y$ and $Z$ independent is to use $$E(2^{X-4})=E(2^Y)E(2^Z)2^{-4}.$$ Perhaps there are some $(Y,Z)$ such that this holds and such that $E(2^Y)$ and $E(2^Z)$ are not so difficult to compute. What do you think?

Comment: Sound great, and I feel stupid that i missed that.
Thanks!

Comment: If you reached a full solution, please write it down and post it as an answer.